# How to move bitcoins to own wallet from other wallet

Tags: wallet, address, transaction-fees

I am new to bitcoin community and I have a website where I want to collect payments through bitcoin or altcoins.

For now I want to know that can I shift my bitcoins from one wallet to another
wallet without paying any fee if yes how can I do this with my limited knowledge
of bitcoin network.

Here is the example of my situation :-

I have generated a bitcoin address for myself called `MainWallet`
now I have generated two bitcoin addresses for my customers to collect payments for example we can say `CustomerWallet1` and `CustomerWallet2` now if my customer pay for their respective orders  let say I got 1 BTC on both customer wallets can I shift this 1 BTC to my `MainWallet` from both of my customer wallets without paying any miner/transaction fee.

If yes how can I do this manually on my windows PC.

Please note : I have private key for all address which I have generated here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean between wallets or between addresses?

Comment: between wallets

Comment: Which wallet solution are you using?

Comment: I will use wallet from bitcoin.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transferring bitcoin between wallets, you can import the private keys for the relevant addresses into the wallet in which you desire to have the bitcoin.

If you mean between addresses, then you will have create and broadcast a transaction with an appropriate fee.

Comment: So if I import my customer wallets into my main wallet can I spend all my balance from my main wallet?

Comment: If you import the private keys for your customer wallets into your main wallet, then you will be able to spend the bitcoin in your customer wallets from the your main wallet.

Comment: Ok, in this case fund are still shown in customer wallet address or my main wallet address?

Comment: Unless the private keys you import into your main wallet will be removed from the customer wallets, the funds will be shown in both.

Comment: Last thing, Is it possible to remove private key from customer wallet after import?

Comment: That will depend on the wallet you are using.