# Sending coins without wallet just address

Tags: transactions, wallet, unconfirmed-transactions

My wallet is not working and is not showing I have any amount of money in my account. I have the wallet address and the transaction record showing that the money is in my account. How can I send this money to another wallet to save it?

Comment: This answer to a similar question may help you. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/67800/71255

Answer (score 1):

By wallet i am assuming its not on exchange. And by coin i am assuming you are talking of **Bitcoin**. So if your coins is stored in bitcoin core qt wallet then you can reuse the private key to sign the transaction.
So if my assumptions is correct than you can go to debug console in your QT wallet and type

`dumpprivkey XYZ`

where xyz is your address which you are saying you know it.
Once you have your private key with you you can use API

```
1) createrawtransaction [{"txid":txid,"vout":n},...] {address:amount,...}
2)signrawtransaction  <hexstring> [{"txid":txid,"vout":n,"scriptPubKey":hex},...] [<privatekey1>,...]
3)sendrawtransaction <hexstring>
```

checkout [apis available](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) in Bitcoin to know more.

Answer (score 0):

To spend a cryptocurrency like bitcoin, you need to sign a transaction with the private keys (which are controlled by your wallet software). Just knowing the address the funds are sitting in does not help you do this, you'll need to get your wallet working in order to move the coins.

Comment: if you are tech savvy, then there is a possibility to find the private key in your corrupted (depending on wallet), that you could then use in another wallet and spend funds from there. Search the forum a bit, there are many entries on lost private keys or corrupted wallets.